# stopPropagation of avform submit event in react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am struggling to stop the propagation of an form submit event inside a modal dialog.

I already understood, that react uses SyntheticEvents and I need to use "event.persist".
But it seems, that it`s not working in the way i use it. Some suggestions would be very helpful.

**I always get the error message:**

*"react-dom.development.js:506 Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're accessing the method `stopPropagation` on a released/nullified synthetic event. This is a no-op function. If you must keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist()."*

```js
  render() {

   const saveXXXEntity = (event, errors, values) => {
      event.persist();
      event.stopPropagation();
   };
    
      <Modal isOpen={this.props.isOpen} toggle={this.props.toggle}>
        <AvForm model={xxxEntity} onSubmit={saveXXXEntity}>

         <ModalHeader>Create New XXX</ModalHeader>
 
         <ModalBody>
             <AvGroup>
               <Label>
                 Name
               </Label>
               <AvField type="text" name="name" />
             </AvGroup>
              
         </ModalBody>
         <ModalFooter>
           
           <Button color="primary" type="submit">
               Create
           </Button>
         </ModalFooter>

        </AvForm>
      </Modal>
    }
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason to do that? I believe `event` is already handled by `AvForm` you can simply just use `values` or `errors`.

Comment: Problem is the propagation of the event "outside" the modal dialog, which triggers another form (in the background) to submit. So I need to access the event to stop propagation. Or do you see another option?